# Using an Array to ask user for 6 integers, then finding number of evens

Tags: java, arrays

So I need to get user input of six integers, I have this part down. But now I am struggling trying to start a way to find out the number of evens and odds. I need to also find the max and min of the input values.

I'm not trying to get anyone to do my homework for me but just point me in the right direction so I can get the ball rolling.

Comment: Please read: [How to start](http://www.patriciashanahan.com/beginner.html).

Comment: Loop through your array of six values and do stuff?  We can help with specific problems you are running into (such as how do I tell if it's even, or how to find the max).

Comment: Could you post the code that you have for reading in the numbers? And perhaps tell us where you're stuck?

Answer (score 2):

To check if a number is even do `if(number % 2 == 0)`.

To get the max value and min value use a for loop through the numbers.  Create ints called min, max, and even. While looping, if the number is even add one to the even int.  If the number is less than the min value set it to the new value.  When making the min and max make it equal to the first value in the loop.  If the max is less than the current number being looped then set the max to the current value being looped.

Answer (score 0):

For even and odds, try taking the last digit of the number or the number itself and find remainder, `(i%2 == 0) (even) else odd.`

For the max and min values I need to know how are you taking the user input. If it is through arrays, then you can run the array and compare all the values with each other to find the max and min values.

```
initially max = 0
max=a[i]
if (a[i+1] > a[i])
then max = a[i+1]
```

Similarly you can do for min values.

Answer (score 0):

```
num%2 == 0 - event
num%2 != 0 - odd
```

Check

```
Arrays.sort()
```

to have sorted array, and then first and last elements will be min/max

Comment: Arrays.sort() just to find min and max?!? That's rather expensive. Not that it matters in this small example, but in a real-world-scenario, the performance impact might be inacceptable.

Comment: 100% agree, for real world it's too expensive, but for this task think OK, not much code and clear

Answer (score 0):

Foreach case of your array, test the value of your case %2 (modulo, basically it's the rest of the division). If the result is 0, it's an even number, if it's 1 it's an odd one.

About the min/max problem, you have to compare cases 2 by 2 and save the min/max of them and continue compare this resultat with the following case until the end of the array.